# Android - Create RelativeLayout object and apply it all the parameters from a layout (xml file)

Tags: android, xml, parameters, android-relativelayout

I've got a `Layout` in "layout" folder which I use as a template. That `Layout` is a `RelativeLayout`. What I want to do is to create a new `RelativeLayout` and apply it the template, I mean, apply all the XML parameters in the template to the new `RelativeLayout`, so I can create elements dynamically with the chosen template. How can I do this? Thanks.

Example:

```
//New RelativeLayout
RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(context);

//RelativeLayout Template
RelativeLayout rl_template = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.template, null);

//Getting all the template params
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = rl_template."getallxmlparams"();

//Applying the params to the New RelativeLayout
rl."setparams"(params);

//Adding the view to a placeholder
placeHolder.addView(rl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inflate it again to different object:

```
RelativeLayout lay1 = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.template, null);

RelativeLayout lay2 = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.template, null);
```

You will get to different objects with same parameters.